# Fragment Layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Fragment in my app. I try to put a Button top of layout but it does not go to top of the layout.

This is my xml of Fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/zirai"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="ZİRAİ"

    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


 <Button
    android:id="@+id/döviz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="DÖVİZ"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

it looks like this :

[image: Emulator screenshot]

I need to put that two button top of the layout
How I can solve this issue

Thanks

Comment: check your Fragment Container if is on the top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a padding or margin attribute in your activity's xml file. Find;

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

or

```
android:marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

and remove them.